# Why is boolean operation making holes in my object?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I'm trying to remove part from a section of a circle using a boolean modifier (difference).

[image: Modifier]

However, after applying the modifier no new faces are added at the intersection so I'm left with hole in my object:

[image: Ater applying the modifier]

Is this normal behaviour? If so, what should I do to avoid these holes?

If I try the same with a sphere instead of a cube then I get the following:
[image]

I'm puzzled...
Using 2.80 RC

Comment: Boolean is finicky. Move your object(s) a tiny bit and you will likely get a better result.

Comment: sometimes the Carve option in the modifier (instead of Bmesh) works better